# Weak$^*$ convergence implies uniform convergence in reflexive Banach space?

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-verification, banach-spaces

I've just written what seems to me like a proof that weak$^*$ convergence implies uniform convergence in a reflexive Banach space, but I'm pretty sure that this can't possibly be true. Could somebody please point out the flaw in the following proof?

We let $X$ be a reflexive Banach space, $X^*$ be its continuous dual, and $\{f_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}\subset X^*$ be a sequence that converges weak$^*$ to $f$ (which is to say, $f_n(x)\to f(x)$ for all $x\in X$). As $X$ is reflexive, the closed unit ball $\overline{B} = \overline{B_1(0)}\subset X$ is weakly compact. For $\epsilon > 0$, we let $\mathcal{F}_{\epsilon} : X\to \mathbb{N}$ be defined by $$\mathcal{F}_{\epsilon}(x) := \sup\{n\in \mathbb{N} : \lvert (f-f_n)(x)\rvert > \epsilon\}$$ and we let $\mathcal{G} : \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{N}\cup \{\infty\}$ be defined by $$\mathcal{G}(\epsilon) := \sup_{x\in \overline{B}} \mathcal{F}_{\epsilon}(x)$$ If $\mathcal{G}(\epsilon) < \infty$ for all $\epsilon > 0$, then we have that for $\epsilon > 0$, $\|f-f_n\| < \epsilon$ for $n > \mathcal{G}(\epsilon)$, and therefore, $\|f-f_n\|\to 0$. If $\mathcal{G}(\epsilon) = \infty$ for some $\epsilon > 0$, then we have some sequence $\{x_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}\subset \overline{B}$ such that $\mathcal{F}_{\epsilon}(x_i)\to \infty$. As $\overline{B}$ is weakly compact, we have some subnet $\langle x_{\alpha}\rangle_{\alpha\in \mathcal{A}}$ of $\langle x_i\rangle_{i\in \mathbb{N}}$ such that

(1) $\mathcal{F}_{\epsilon}(x_{\alpha})\to \infty$, and

(2) $\langle x_{\alpha}\rangle_{\alpha\in \mathcal{A}}$ converges weakly to some $x\in \overline{B}$, which is to say that $\langle g(x_{\alpha})\rangle_{\alpha\in \mathcal{A}}$ converges to $g(x)$ for all $g\in X^*$.

Therefore, we have that $\langle (f-f_n)(x_{\alpha})\rangle_{\alpha\in \mathcal{A}}$ converges to $(f-f_n)(x)$ for all $n$. For $N\in \mathbb{N}$, there is an $\alpha'\in \mathcal{A}$ such that for all $\alpha\geq \alpha'$ in $\mathcal{A}$, $\mathcal{F}_{\epsilon}(x_{\alpha}) > N$, which implies that $\lvert (f-f_n)(x_{\alpha})\rvert > \epsilon$ for some $n > N$ for all $\alpha\geq \alpha'$. But, as $(f-f_n)(x_{\alpha})$ converges to $(f-f_n)(x)$, we have some $\alpha''$ such that $\lvert (f-f_n)(x-x_{\alpha})\rvert < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$ for all $\alpha\geq \alpha''$. Therefore, for $\alpha\geq \max(\alpha', \alpha'')$, $\lvert (f-f_n)(x-x_{\alpha})\rvert < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$ and $\lvert (f-f_n)(x_{\alpha})\rvert > \epsilon$, so $\lvert (f-f_n)(x)\rvert > \frac{\epsilon}{2}$ for some $n > N$. As $N$ can be arbitrarily large, we have that $\lvert (f-f_n)(x)\rvert\not\to 0$, which contradicts that $f_n$ converges weak$^*$ to $f$. Therefore, $\mathcal{G}(\epsilon) < \infty$ for all $\epsilon > 0$, so $\|f-f_n\|\to 0$.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I got confused by the last part of your proof, but I guess that you interchange the limits w.r.t. $\alpha$ and $n$. You can also apply your arguments to a simple sequence, e.g., $f_n = e_n$ in $\ell^2$.

Comment: Actually, I think I realized what the mistake is. The way I wrote the proof obscures that $\alpha''$ is dependent on $n$, and $n$ is dependent on $\alpha$, so $\alpha\geq \max(\alpha', \alpha'')$ could be more explicitly written as $\alpha\geq \max(\alpha', \alpha''(n(\alpha)))$, which is likely never true. My guess is that for any $n(\alpha)$ we define, the $\alpha''$ we get is always going to be bigger than $\alpha$.

Comment: I think the argument is fixable, though. Give me maybe 5 minutes.

Comment: Never mind. Rewriting the convergence of $\lvert (f-f_n)(x-x_{\alpha})\rvert$ to $0$ in terms of $n$ just gives us an $N$ dependent on $\alpha$, which presents the same issues (for $N(\alpha)$, we get an $\alpha'(N(\alpha))$, and we therefore need $\alpha\geq \alpha'(N(\alpha))$). Alright, I think I can call this one debunked!